# How paging in Linux distinguishes pages from page frames?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

The book Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition 
By Daniel P. Bovet, Marco Cesati 
talks about advantages of Paging in Chapter 2 Memory Addressing.

Here it says one of the advantages is,

Distinguish pages (groups of data) from page frames (physical addresses in main memory). This allows the same page to be stored in a page frame, then saved to disk and later reloaded in a different page frame. This is the basic ingredient of the virtual memory mechanism.

I am unable to fully understand this. Does it mean that the when a swapped page is loaded back in the Physical memory, its virtual address remains the same but the Physical address changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process address space is organized into logical pages. A logical page may be mapped to a physical page frame.

> Does it mean that the when a swapped page is loaded back in the Physical memory, its virtual address remains the same but the Physical address changes?

It means a lot more than that. However, yes, a logical page may be mapped to different physical page frames over time.